# How to populate a column given paramter value passed through an expression?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Is it possible to populate a column with a parameter value(column name) passed on via an expression?

Edit:
I have a dataset that's getting its data from a stored procedure that's doing some pivots and pulling data from multiple databases. The problem is that some of the data is dynamic and can have unknown number of columns but I do know the max number of columns. The first five or so columns are static and I've already added those to the report.

What I'm trying to do is to create placeholder for a maximum number of columns and then only show/populate columns that the user picks (the user can also pick to show all).

Comment: probably but without a lot more info and exactly what you are trying to do you won't get any meaningful answers. Describe the data, describe the report design and expected output. Post images of report designs if applicable

Comment: I've added some more information.

Comment: Will all columns come back from the query and your idea is to hide the column based on user selection, or do you just need to display the columns that come back from the query in a dynamic column group?

Comment: a bit of both but basically just display the columns returned by the query.